# How to edit Canvas-Objects appearance?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got a canvas with the id=canvas and in this canvas are many balls. I need to add some information to these balls. So I've got a ball with the text="ball1" on it. And I need to add some text under this line, something like text2="My Super Ball".

Also I know the radius and coordinates of the balls.

How can I do so if I only got the canvas and ball id?

Comment: You need to know the position and radius of the ball inside the canvas, otherwise you don't know where to put your "My Super Ball" string.

Comment: Sorry, I have the radius and the coordinates, but I dont know how to update it everytime the ball moves or is getting bigger or something like that.

Comment: You probably have a js file or a `<script>` element coming with your canvas. Read the text in it, find where these info are defined, tweak it => You're now a programmer.

Comment: I'm not able to edit these files, but I can add JavaScript to the whole website. And I know what parameters the balls have, but I dont know how to add stuff to it.

Comment: If you cannot edit the js that draws the balls then you cannot get the information you need.  Once drawn all that exists in the canvas are pixels.  There are no objects, no sprite coordinates or anything of the sort available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem: You can't change anything that's already been drawn on the html5 canvas**

*So...*

You've been given a canvas with **existing** text-ball drawings and you need to change the text in one of the balls.

*But...*

Html5 canvas is like a real wall painting. You draw a red ball with "ball1" on the canvas and hang it on the wall. You can't later change the "ball1" text by replacing it with "My Super Ball".

**Option#1: Redraw everything on the canvas**

If the canvas contains only balls (==`context.arc`) filled with text (==`context.fillText`), then you can erase the entire canvas with `context.clearRect` and redraw the text-balls with your desired text.

**Option#2: Redraw just the ball(s) that need text changes**

If the canvas contains content that you don't want to destroy by clearing the canvas, then you can over-write a ball by refilling it with its original color and then drawing your changed text inside the refilled ball.

**Here's example annotated code & a demo showing both methods:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// create an array of "ball" objects 
// Each object contains sufficient info to redraw a ball
var balls=[
    {x:100,y:100,radius:50,fill:'red',text:'ball1'},
    {x:200,y:100,radius:35,fill:'blue',text:'ball2'},
    {x:300,y:100,radius:25,fill:'green',text:'ball3'},
];

// To start, draw the basic balls
drawAll();

// listen for button clicks
$('#redrawAll').click(function(){
    // toggle the super ball: ball1 <-> super
    var b=balls[0];
    if(b.text=='ball1'){
        b.text='My Super Ball';
    }else{
        b.text='ball1';
    }
    // completely clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // redraw all balls
    drawAll();
});
//
$('#overwriteOne').click(function(){
    // toggle the super ball: ball1 <-> super
    var b=balls[0];
    if(b.text=='ball1'){
        b.text='My Super Ball';
    }else{
        b.text='ball1';
    }
    // over-write just the super ball
    drawTextBall(b.x,b.y,b.radius,b.fill,b.text);
});

function drawAll(){
    // completely clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // redraw all balls from the info in balls[] array
    for(var i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
        var b=balls[i];
        drawTextBall(b.x,b.y,b.radius,b.fill,b.text);
    }
}

function drawTextBall(x,y,radius,fill,text){
    // this function changes some styles so we'll be kind and
    // restore the incoming style when we're done.
    ctx.save();
    // draw a red ball at x,y
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    ctx.fill();
    // draw text centered at x,y
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='middle';
    ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
    // restore the original incoming styles
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='redrawAll'>Clear and Redraw all balls</button>
<button id='overwriteOne'>Overwrite just 1 ball</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=200></canvas>
```